# How can I change what is printed when I type an object name?

Tags: r, printing, methods

The function ezANOVA in the ez package calculates an ANOVA.  Often I want to look at the means inside of these cells.  Normally I just retype the formula and use the summaryBy function.  This morning I modified the ezANOVA function so that it included in its resulting object the data required to do a summaryBy command.  How can I change the object resulting from ezANOVA to by default hide this extra data when printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little obscure.  If you are returning an object with a class you can modify the print or show method for the corresponding class.  You will have to know if you are dealing with an S3 or S4 class.  loos at `?methods` of `?Methods` for details.  as a quick example if you return an s3 class 'ezANOVA'  you define a function.

```
print.ezANOVA<-function(x){
   #code for formatting the ezANOVA object nice.
}
```

**Update**
In light of your comment, and that you have already modified the exANOVA function.  add this to the end of ezANOVA.

```
class(return.value)<-"ezANOVA"
return(return.value)
```

then add the `print.ezANOVA` function and that should handle it.

Comment: My understanding of R's object handling is very weak.  Such that I'm not exactly sure what type of result ezANOVA is returning.  It may not be a class at all - in fact I think it is returning a list.  Perhaps your answer means I should try to wrap the function as an object and then I'll have the sort of functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Your update provided exactly the information I needed.